# Convert number to tkinter color

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a simple way to convert a number into a tkinter color (`#ffeedd`).

I'm already setup to take the number and multiply it by 8 to give me a bit more color range leeway, and maybe even multiply it by 16 depending on just how much leeway I have to work with, not sure on how much leeway I will have yet... but I'm guessing I'll only be able to multiply by 8. How do I take that number and convert it over so I can use it with `canvas.create_line((x,y), (x,y), fill = 'color')`. I tried `hex(number)` but it just gives me back that color `0x0` doesn't exists... kinda figured that would happen but thought it would be worth a try.

```
a = 326
b = a * 8
canvas.create_line((x,y), (x,y), fill = b)
```

Comment: What `color` should your int number represent?

Comment: b.  The value that b comes out to.  The number won't always the be same hence why I need to be able to convert from a number to '#0efe58' format.  b won't always equal 326 * 8.  In the instance above it does, but that won't always be the case.  I'll be going through a database and populating the screen depending on calculations performed on the database.

Comment: Yeah, sure `b`, but you have to convert your number to an `rgb` value following some rules. Or you you just want to have (random) different colors for different numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you have 3 or 6 hex digits. For instance:

```
frame.configure(background="#{0:06X}".format(0x808080))
```

The actual permitted set of color specfications is given in the [GetColor](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/GetColor.htm)
manual page.

Comment: Or 9 digits (hex) also

Comment: Okay, this idea, with some recoding and some nice manipulating of the negative numbers is working.  Thanks.